# SQL Server auto increment Null values from specified starting value

Tags: sql-server

I am looking for a solution to handle invoice numbers in a SQL Server table.

[image]

How the system works: on load the system queries a cloud-based accounting package for the last invoice number used. On retrieval of this number the system enters the number into table 2 (replacing the number that existed previously).

When processing invoices, the system should query table 2 for the last used invoice number and increment it by 1 for the first row in table 1 where the invoice number is NULL, and then increment each row after that by 1, where the invoice number is NULL.

I can't use an auto increment row for the entire table as an invoice run (batch of invoices processed together) could have a starting invoice number that isn't equal to the last invoice number plus 1 – the reason being is this system is designed solely to handle the invoices of a single customer, other invoices may have been created for other customers from within the accounts package.

I can't use SQL Server to automate the process as invoice numbers could change on the accounts package and not be reflected in the database – there is no relationship between SQL Server & the accounts package; therefore I would need to manually run an update statement from my application.

I have looked at using RESEED as outlined in the following suggested answer - but I don't think it will solve my problem:

[Reset IDENTITY value](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43910/reset-identity-value)

Any ideas, help, table design suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Will `Sequence Numbers` suites your requirement ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sequence-numbers/sequence-numbers?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: `SEQUENCE` seems like the right choice, but your description appears to imply you have a different table for each customer, which is a major design flaw; it should be one table with a column to denote who that customer is. Then `IDENTITY` would work too.

Comment: Rolling your own auto-increment will eventually cause bugs in your system. You'll either get wrong numbers or deadlocks - You really should find a way to let SQL Server handle the auto-increment for you.

Comment: There is 1 customer in the entire database. The application is solely designed to handle their invoices - they have a specific invoicing process that requires their invoices to be generated outside a standard accounting package. The accounting package is used for handling payments in / payments out - the idea of keeping the invoicing numbers inline with the accounts package is to protect the accounts package from exploding if it spots a gap in the invoicing numbers.

Comment: Your table STILL needs a primary key that is independent of this "cloud system" so that you can reference any particular row. But is seems you confuse the two. If identity and sequence do not work for you, then you must "calculate" it in some fashion - sequential number is a common and frequently discussed question.

Comment: Their is an ID column on the table - there is another 20 columns on the table - I just did not display them to simplify the question

Comment: @ZoharPeled - I should have mentioned there is an auto increment column on the table, I apologise. I am solely looking for a solution to increment values in an int column

Comment: Hint - row_number and simply add the starting value to it.

Comment: Nice Hint - I'll test today